# Is ALL function redundant when there is MAX function inside it in sql?

Tags: sql

I'm now practicing sql on sqlzoo.
It occurs to me that why we need ALL function when we got MAX function inside it, since MAX function outputs only a single value?

What difference will it cause when we exclude the ALL function?

```
SELECT name FROM bbc
 WHERE population > ALL
       (SELECT MAX(population)
          FROM bbc
         WHERE region = 'Europe')
   AND region = 'South Asia'
```

Answer (score 1):

These expressions:

```
WHERE population > ALL (SELECT population
                        FROM bbc
                        WHERE bbc.region = 'Europe'
                       )
```

and:

```
WHERE population > (SELECT MAX(population)
                    FROM bbc
                    WHERE bbc.region = 'Europe'
                   )
```

are almost exactly the same.  The difference occurs when the `WHERE` clause filters out all rows.  In that case `population > ALL (. . .)` evaluates to true.  However, `population > (SELECT MAX() . . .)` does not.

The reason is the `NULL` value.  With no matches `MAX()` evaluates to `NULL`.

The same logic should apply in your case.  If the `WHERE` filters out all rows, then `MAX()` returns `NULL`.  The `ALL` will not evaluate to `true`, because of the `NULL`.  However, if you leave out the `ALL`, it should return all rows.

Answer (score 0):

All operator is required only for when your results come in multiple rows. When your results come in a single row using the max keyword or top 1 at that time "ALL" operator is not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `ALL` is not a function, it's an operator.

Secondly, your query should change depend on what is your expected result (This involve to `NULL` problem in SQL)

If you need to return some rows even when the subquery return no row (in this case i.e. there's no region `'Europe'`) then you should use `ALL` or `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT name FROM bbc
WHERE population > ALL (
        SELECT population
        FROM bbc
        WHERE region = 'Europe')
    AND region = 'South Asia;
```

(assume there're some name in `region = 'South Asia'`)

If you want to return no row if the subquery return no row then you should use

```
SELECT name FROM bbc
WHERE population > (
        SELECT MAX(population)
        FROM bbc
        WHERE region = 'Europe'
    )
    AND region = 'South Asia;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rewrite your query, this generates no rows:

```
select * from generate_series(1,10) x
where x > all(select max(t) from generate_series(1,5) t where t = 100);
```

[image]

And so is this:

```
select * from generate_series(1,10) y
where y > (select max(t) from generate_series(1,5) t where t = 100);
```

[image]

The following might be your desired query. That is, it will show countries that have population greater than ALL of europe's countries population; and if europe don't have any more countries (WHERE region = 'europe' yields no rows, so it could be considered zero population), and you need to show those countries that have population greater than europe's zero population, use this instead: `field > all (select another_field`:

```
select * from generate_series(1,10) z
where z > all(select t from generate_series(1,5) t where t = 100)
```

ALL is not redundant. `field > (SELECT MAX(` might not yield the desired results. Besides, ALL has better semantics.

In your question's query though, the ALL is redundant, as you are using MAX. Most of the time, ALL is not intended to be used in conjunction with MAX. `field > ALL (SELECT another_field` would suffice.

[image]